# How to code coverage a promise inside functions while unit testing using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage

How to code cover then and catch function of a promise inside a function while unit testing using jest? Please see code below.

Service.js

```
export const userLogin = data => {
  return AjaxService.post(
    "http://localhost/3000/signin", data
  ).then(
    res => {
      return res.data;
    },
    error => {
      return error.response.data;
    }
  );
};
```

AjaxService.js

```
export const AjaxService = {
  post: (url, data, headers) => {
    return axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: url,
      headers: headers || { "content-type": "application/json" },
      data: data
    });
  }
```

}

Example.js

```
class Login extends Component {

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (this.props.handleSubmit) this.props.handleSubmit(); 
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: true})
    userLogin().then((res) => {
     // when promise resolve
     var response = res;
    }, (err) => {
      // when promise reject  
      var error = err;
    })
  }
  render() {
   return (
    <form id="login-form" onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)} >
     <input type="username" />
     <input type="password" />
     <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
   )
  }

}
```

Example.test.js

```
it("test login form submit ", () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Login />);
    let instance = wrapper.instance(); // get class instance
    instance.handleSubmit(); // will trigger component method
    let actualVal = wrapper.state().isLoggedIn; // get state key value
    expect(true).to.eql(actualVal);
  });
```

After generating coverage report using `--coverage` in Jest

[image]

We can see that the code inside promise success and error function doesn't get covered as part of unit testing. So please help cover this. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't get covered because your unit test is done before the code gets run. Jest also has an syntax for asynchronous tests, but it can be tricky to use in your situation.

Comment: Where `userLogin` function come from?

Comment: @slideshowp2, I have updated question. Please check.

Comment: @SurajAJ how do you get those pink highlights in source code?

Comment: @RahulYadav, after generating code coverage report there will be folder generated named 'coverage' in root folder, you can run 'index.html' inside that folder to view report in above format for each files included in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution, folder structure:

```sh
.
├── ajaxService.ts
├── example.spec.tsx
├── example.tsx
└── service.ts
```

`ajaxService.ts`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const AjaxService = {
  post: (url, data, headers?) => {
    return axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url,
      headers: headers || { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      data
    });
  }
};
```

`service.ts`:

```js
import { AjaxService } from './ajaxService';

export const userLogin = data => {
  return AjaxService.post('http://localhost/3000/signin', data).then(
    res => {
      return res.data;
    },
    error => {
      return error.response.data;
    }
  );
};
```

`example.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { userLogin } from './service';

export interface ILoginProps {
  handleSubmit(): void;
}

interface ILoginState {
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
}

export class Login extends Component<ILoginProps, ILoginState> {
  constructor(props: ILoginProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false
    };
  }
  public handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.props.handleSubmit) {
      this.props.handleSubmit();
    }
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });

    const data = {};
    return userLogin(data).then(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
  }
  public render() {
    return (
      <form id="login-form" onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
        <input type="username" />
        <input type="password" />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

`example.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Login, ILoginProps } from './example';
import * as service from './service';

describe('Login', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  const mockedProps: ILoginProps = { handleSubmit: jest.fn() };
  const mockedFormEvent = { preventDefault: jest.fn() };
  const mockedUserLoginResponse = 'mocked data';
  const mockedUserLoginError = new Error('database error');

  it('test login form submit - 1', done => {
    const userLoginSpy = jest.spyOn(service, 'userLogin').mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedUserLoginResponse);
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const wrapper = shallow(<Login {...mockedProps}></Login>);
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', mockedFormEvent);

    setImmediate(() => {
      expect(mockedFormEvent.preventDefault).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockedProps.handleSubmit).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(wrapper.state('isLoggedIn')).toBeTruthy();
      expect(userLoginSpy).toBeCalledWith({});
      expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith(mockedUserLoginResponse);
      done();
    });
  });

  it('test login form submit - 2', async () => {
    const userLoginSpy = jest.spyOn(service, 'userLogin').mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedUserLoginResponse);
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const wrapper = shallow(<Login {...mockedProps}></Login>);
    await (wrapper.instance() as any).handleSubmit(mockedFormEvent);
    expect(mockedFormEvent.preventDefault).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockedProps.handleSubmit).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(wrapper.state('isLoggedIn')).toBeTruthy();
    expect(userLoginSpy).toBeCalledWith({});
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith(mockedUserLoginResponse);
  });

  it('test login error - 1', done => {
    const userLoginSpy = jest.spyOn(service, 'userLogin').mockRejectedValueOnce(mockedUserLoginError);
    const errorLogSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'error');
    const wrapper = shallow(<Login {...mockedProps}></Login>);
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', mockedFormEvent);

    setImmediate(() => {
      expect(mockedFormEvent.preventDefault).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockedProps.handleSubmit).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(wrapper.state('isLoggedIn')).toBeTruthy();
      expect(userLoginSpy).toBeCalledWith({});
      expect(errorLogSpy).toBeCalledWith(mockedUserLoginError);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58110463/example.spec.tsx
  Login
    ✓ test login form submit - 1 (16ms)
    ✓ test login form submit - 2 (3ms)
    ✓ test login error - 1 (10ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    mocked data

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    mocked data

  console.error node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    Error: database error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/58110463/example.spec.tsx:14:32)
        at addSpecsToSuite (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:496:51)
        at Env.describe (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:466:11)
        at describe (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/jasmineLight.js:81:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/58110463/example.spec.tsx:6:1)
        at Runtime._execModule (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:888:13)
        at Runtime._loadModule (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:577:12)
        at Runtime.requireModule (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:433:10)
        at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:201:13
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:27:24)
        at _next (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:47:9)
        at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:52:7
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:44:12
        at _jasmine (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:206:19)
        at jasmine2 (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:60:19)
        at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:385:24
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:161:24)
        at _next (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:181:9)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File            |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files       |    86.21 |       50 |    63.64 |    84.62 |                   |
 ajaxService.ts |    66.67 |        0 |        0 |    66.67 |                 5 |
 example.tsx    |      100 |       75 |      100 |      100 |                21 |
 service.ts     |       40 |      100 |        0 |       40 |             4,6,9 |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.035s, estimated 6s
```

HTML coverage report:

[image]

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58110463

Comment: After (return)ing the promise inside the method and using async await it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use the `async await` sintax:

```
it("test login form submit ", async () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Login />);
    let instance = wrapper.instance(); // get class instance
    await instance.handleSubmit(); // will trigger component method
    let actualVal = wrapper.state().isLoggedIn; // get state key value
    expect(true).to.eql(isLoggedIn);
  });
```

Then, your test will "wait" until the promise is resolved or rejected and it will run inside the `then` or the  `catch`. You can learn more about how Jest manages the asynchronous code [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async).

In addition, if you are going to work with a lot of promises, I recommend you to take a look to the [wait-for-expect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-for-expect) package. It could really help you to code your tests.

Comment: This will work only if the method itself is the promise. In current scenario, the promise is inside the method.